# jQuery function fails after .html() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap drop down button that after the user clicks on it the controller loads and responds with JS in which it re-renders the html from a partial.

In the Bootstrap drop down button I have `<ul class="dropdown-menu keep-open">` where the keep-open class is used by:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.keep-open').on 'click': (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
    return
```

To keep the drop down open when you click in it vs. closing by default (I have a form in the drop down).  The call works fine until I submit the for and the controller JS re-renders the button then the `keep-open` stops working and the drop down menu keeps closing.

Can I either keep this menu open another way or what is preventing the `$('.keep-open').on 'click'` from being called again?

Comment: $('body').on('click' , '.keep-open' , function(){})

Comment: Just add that `$('.keep-open').on 'click'` handler again after you re-render button.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the commenters, your problem arises from your directly bound event handler. The handler is only called when the event occurs on the exact element to which it was bound. Your re-render removes the original element, and the newly created element does not have a handler attached.

You can likely solve this problem by using a delegated event handler instead:

```
$('body').on('click' , '.keep-open' , function() { ... });
```

You should see the section on 'Direct and delegated events' in the [jQuery .on() docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks - that was perfect.  So to paraphrase - my old code was bound to the html on the page (document).  When I changed it even though I still had the .keep-open class in my code the JS was looking for the old content which I destroyed when I called .html.  This new code is watching the page regardless if it changes.